# Showing $\sup\limits_{y\neq 0}\int\limits_{|x|\ge2|y|}\frac{|y|^{\delta}}{|x|^{n+\delta}}dx< \infty$

Tags: integration, supremum-and-infimum, estimation

> Showing $\sup\limits_{y\neq 0}\int\limits_{|x|\ge2|y|}\frac{|y|^{\delta}}{|x|^{n+\delta}}dx< \infty$, where $\delta>0$ and $n$ is the dimension

First, if $n\ge2$ then under normal circumstances the integral should be finite, but what happens if you take the supremum, does l'Hôpital imply that there's also then no problem ? And for $n=1$ I'm not sure if the claim is still true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\displaystyle\int_{|x|\geq 2|y|}\dfrac{|y|^{\delta}}{|x|^{n+\delta}}dx\\
=\omega_{n-1}\displaystyle\int_{2|y|}^{\infty}\dfrac{|y|^{\delta}}{r^{n+\delta}}r^{n-1}dr\\
=\omega_{n-1}|y|^{\delta}\dfrac{1}{\delta}\dfrac{1}{2^{\delta}|y|^{\delta}}\\
=\omega_{n-1}\dfrac{1}{\delta 2^{\delta}}$

Comment: Thanks, $\omega_{n-1}$ is the volume of the sphere or something ?

Comment: It is the surface area of the unit sphere.